# Drives turned into Simple Volume, CANNOT reformat

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive

All of my HDs turned into Simple Volume. A month ago I was deleting some GB of the C: Drive to create a temporary one to store my stuff in so I can reformat. Ever since then I can NOT reformatand the problem is I think, most likely is because my HD turnt into A simple Volume.

I have 3 drives that is Simple Volume now - Local Disk (C:/) Recovery (D:/) & HP Tools (E:/)

I tried the easeus app to repair it back, but the Drive HP_TOOLS will not let me recover [For some reason, IDK!)

Is there ANY way to solve this problem? Preferable not losing my files? I do not have a backup storage any where.

Specs:

```
HP G61 Notebook PC
Windows 7
64-Bit
```

Anymore questions, please ask.

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/188674/c-turned-into-simple-volume-unable-to-do-a-factory-reset-on-windows-7 of 14 September

Answer (score 0):

Those drives should be "Simple Volumes" the alternatives are "Spanned, Striped, Mirrored, and Raid-5" all of those require multiple hard drives to work together as one and since your computer has a Recovery and HP Tools partition I think its pretty safe to say your computer was not setup that way.

If I am reading this correctly you shrunk your C:\ drive to have a temporary storage location for files so you could reinstall and you are trying to recover those GB...

If this is the case you need to go into Disk Management by clicking the Start Menu and typing "Create and format hard disk partitions" in the Search programs box... should be only one link on the list to click.

Since you didn't list the GB you used to temporarily store the information I am going to assume you already deleted it so you don't need to... If you didn't you will need to right click on it and delete the partition/volume after you removed your files from it.

Then right click on drive C:\ click "Extend Volume" then follow the instructions to add those GB to the C:\ again.